# Sumif values across a range into 1 cell

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sumifs

HI I have a have two columns with numbers. If the right column is greater than the left I want the differences summed. The thing is I need them in one column. 
I have tried to sumif, but it just keeps taking the first cell in the second column

```
SUMIF(A1:A5,">"&$B1$1:$B$5,B1:B5)

   A    B
1  1    1
2  2    2
3  4    2
4  5    4
5  1    4             output=3
```

Comment: Fixed question formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5>B1:B5),A1:A5-B1:B5)
```

Comment: When i run this i get an output of 3. Essentially i need to take the cells where A >B and the take the sum of the differences into one cell

Comment: You question does not refer to the difference.

Comment: So in excel, if a formula calls for an array, you do not need the curl brackets?

Comment: Thanks man appreciate it, Last thing. would you be able to clarify the -- at the beginning i see taking one out makes it negative and both makes it 0

Comment: the `--` turns the TRUE/FALSE that is returned by `(A1:A5>B1:B5)` to 1/0 respectively.  Thus when false the result of that row is 0 and when true the result is the difference.